# How to get Hour and minutes in decimal format from two dates

Tags: sql-server

Here is my query

```
select  DATEDIFF(minute, '2015-06-10 14:00:00.000', '2015-06-10 16:50:00.000') / 60.0
```

I get `2.833333` but i want `2.50`

Comment: It's giving the correct output, you are expecting the wrong result.

Comment: You can't have 2.5 hours and expect it to be 2 hour 50 minutes, what would 2.9 be, 2 hours and 90 minutes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gives you what you asked for, but please keep in mind that usually 2.50 is equal to 2.5 and means 5/2; you are using a notation that it is quite uncommon

```
DECLARE @f float
DECLARE @t nvarchar(15)

SELECT @f = DATEDIFF(hour, '2015-06-10 14:00:00.000', '2015-06-10 16:50:00.000')
SELECT @t = CONVERT(nvarchar(10), @f) + N'.' + CONVERT(nvarchar(10), (DATEDIFF(minute, '2015-06-10 14:00:00.000', '2015-06-10 16:50:00.000') - @f*60))
SELECT @t
```

Answer (score 1):

So you want to show the hours and minutes? You could use this:

```
DECLARE @t1 datetime
SET @t1 = '2015-06-10 14:00:00.000'
DECLARE @t2 datetime
SET  @t2 = '2015-06-10 16:50:00.000'

SELECT HHmm = CONVERT(varchar(3), DATEDIFF(minute, @t1, @t2) / 60) 
             + '.' 
             + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2), DATEDIFF(minute, @t1, @t2) % 60), 2)
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7/211/0)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

The `DateDiff` function returns an integer. to display it as time you need to use some math and casting:

```
DECLARE @FromDate datetime = '2015-06-10 14:00:00.000',
        @ToDate datetime = '2015-06-10 16:50:00.000'

select CAST(DATEDIFF(minute, @FromDate, @ToDate) / 60 as varchar) + ':' + 
       CAST(DATEDIFF(minute, @FromDate, @ToDate) % 60 as varchar)
```